# "Усердный" - при чем тут сердце?

Tags: этимология

Тут обсуждалось слово "старание", и там автор вопроса привел эпитет "усердие". Мне подумалось, что это тоже любопытное слово.
Его можно разложить на "у-сердие", то есть, "у сердца". Я так понимаю, что подразумевается, что некто работает от всего сердца (хотя от всего сердца обычно поздравляют или желают что-то). Но тогда логичнее было бы сказать "отсердие". Но почему тут приставка "у-"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне нравится Ваш ход мысли:

> Его можно разложить на "у-сердие", то есть, "у сердца"... Но почему тут приставка "у-"?

В словарях имеется устаревшее значение слова УСЕРДНЫЙ - 1. устар.
Сердечно расположенный, горячо преданный, приверженный кому-, чему-л.
[Дворня] окружила молодого барина с шумными изъявлениями радости. Насилу мог он продраться сквозь их усердную толпу. Пушкин, Дубровский.
 (http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/73213/%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Сердечно расположенный и есть расположенный У СЕРДЦА, близкий сердцу, отсюда - горячий в переносном смысле , т.е интенсивный - ревностный - старательный - все значения входят в семантический ряд.

Answer (score 3):

Слово "усердие" заимствовано из ст.-сл языка  11-13 веках (от усрьдый - усердный).

Интересно, что слова "сердце и сердить" являются однокоренными. Сердце считалось вместилищем различных сильных чувств: любви и злости, волнения и стремления.

Соответственно, можно предположить существование промежуточного глагола "усердить"  -  взволновать, вдохновить, где приставка У будет обозначать полную завершенность действия (качать - укачать, равнять - уравнять). Сравнить: усердить - рассердить, здесь приставка  РАС обозначает совершение действия с большой интенсивностью.

Тогда "усердие" - это  вдохновение, энтузиазм, которое человек проявляет в различных делах, но при этом оно считается только конструктивным, положительным качеством.

Comment: Хотелось бы поинтересоваться, а что такое **бессердечие**? 

Спрошу здесь, чтобы не создавать почти аналогичную тему. Недопонимаю это слово.

Comment: Сердце - это, как правило,  олицетворение светлых человеческих чувств: любви, доброты,  сострадания, понимания. Человеку "без сердца" такие чувства недоступны, и о  значении слова бессердечный можно судить по ряду синонимов: безжалостный, жестокий, немилосердный, холодный, черствый, бездушный. В то же время существует выражения "в сердцах", связанное с негативными эмоциями, то есть сделать что-либо в порыве гнева, расстройства, раздражения.

Comment: Спасибо, @София!